# How can I verify a MySQL row creation date in a JavaScript integration test?

Tags: mysql, node.js, jestjs, momentjs

I'm writing an integration test for a "create" method in a Node data-access module that works with a MySQL database. Our MySQL table has a `created_at` field, type of `timestamp` that defaults to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Say my table looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `some_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `column1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `column2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

What I would like to do is test that the `created_at` field is getting set as expected, say, that it is the same or after when the test started execution. I'm trying to use Moment's [`isSameOrAfter`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-after/) with it's [`utc()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) parsing ability, but I can't figure it out. Say my test looks something like this:

```
test('created_at is set on creation', async () => {
  // must use UTC since CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is UTC
  const now = moment.utc();
  // newObject is a POJO of the newly created row in some_table
  const newObject = await someTableLib.create(args);
  // this does not work for some reason
  expect(moment.utc(newObject.created_at).isSameOrAfter(now)).toBe(true);
})
```

I've also tried not using `utc()` to parse the database date:

```
expect(moment(newObject.created_at).isSameOrAfter(now)).toBe(true);
```

How can I best test that the database is setting `created_at` as expected?

**EDIT**
Some example values that I see when I throw in some `console.log()` statements (though I'm not sure how best to compare the values from Moment in a `console.log`):

```
console.log(newObject.created_at);
// 2020-04-08T14:50:46.000Z
console.log(moment.utc(newObject.created_at).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
// 2020-04-08 14:50:46
console.log(now.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
// 2020-04-08 14:50:46
```

**EDIT 2**
I am now completely confused. If I format the moment objects, then re-initialize them as moment objects, THEN compare them, it works:

```
const testStart = moment(now.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
const created = moment(moment.utc(newObject.created_at).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
expect(created.isSameOrAfter(testStart)).toBe(true);  // this passes!!
```

Comment: Did you try logging the values of now and created_at? This will give you a pretty good idea about timezone differences between your server and client. Another suggestion is to try to avoid tests like this. It's better to rely on the DB library's return value for evaluating the success or failure of transaction. Like some DB handlers return the ID of newly created record, whereas others return true or false.

Comment: @VPaul I am just doing that now and will edit the OP with example values.

Comment: @VPaul and you're right, perhaps I shouldn't be testing this. But now I'm really curious as to why it's not working and am having trouble letting it go :)

Comment: That's strange. I would suggest to cast the formatted date i.e. the way you have logged for debugging, to moment instance and then compare.

Comment: @VPaul That is messed up! I did as you suggested and it passes! See my edit again. I'm going to leave it open to see if anyone can tell me _why_ the heck it would behave like this, but if no one answers in a reasonable amount of time, you should answer so I can accept.

Comment: I think I know why this might be happening. There may be a difference in your server and client time-zone by milliseconds. So you are getting the result from the back-end which is not in sync with the client and moment is comparing till the last fraction available, which shows the wrong result. It may run fine by passing the precision in `isSameOrAfter` to minutes IMO (https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/05-is-same-or-after/).

Comment: @VPaul That's it! If I specify 'minute' or 'second' for `isSameOrAfter`, it works, but fails if it does not. Thank you! Please post your comment as an answer so I can upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a mismatch in server (DB server) and client (App server) times by milliseconds or a fraction. In this case, it seems like the server's time is ahead of the client's, which always returns `created_at` (from the server) less than `now` (from the client in the test case).

In order to resolve this, we can pass precision to moment's `isSameOrAfter` function as 'minute' or 'second', so that it ignores the smaller fractions when comparing the two. Please refer to the docs (https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/05-is-same-or-after/) to know how to pass precision to this function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using momentjs you can try using unix timestamp which is both supported by MySQL (in seconds) and javascript (in ms)

```
test('difference in time should be within a second', () => {
  x = query("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) AS x FROM ...");
  expect(x).toBeCloseTo(Date.now() / 1000, 0);
});
```